# Faster calculation of onset days for rainy season

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have a huge set of csv datafiles (ca. 4 million) and each file contains climate data (temp, precip etc.) for 30 years. I want to use these data to calculate the onset of the rainy season. Each file corresponds to the cell of a grid (2544 rows x 1928 columns). I wrote a for loop to calculate the onset days for every row, resulting in a file with 57.840 rows (1928 x 30). The scripts works fine, but it takes about 18 minutes for row, which means that I would need 31.8 days to finish all calculations.

Does anyone have any idea on how to speed up these calculations?

Here is the code:

```
#SET PATH WORKING DIRECTORY
path="Z:/md/projects/.../climate-data/row-0"
setwd(path)
files <- list.files(path =path, full.names = T, recursive = T, pattern=glob2rx("*col*.csv*")) 

results<-data.frame()
name <- strsplit(path, "/")[[1]][6]

for (file in files){
     asc<-read.table(file, sep=",", skip=0, header=T) 
     name2 <- strsplit(file, "/")[[1]][7]
     name2<-str_sub(name2,-nchar(name2),-5)
     Q<-mean(asc$precip)
     x<-1
vector <- vector("numeric")
    for (i in 1:12){
       for (j in 1:31){
       d<-asc[ which(asc$month == i  & asc$day == j) , ]
       d<-mean(d$prec)
       vector[x] <-d # get average precipitation per day
       x<-x+1
     }
   } 
   vector<-vector[ !is.na(vector)] # delete NA values
   vector<-vector-Q # substract annual precipitation from daily precipitation 
   vector<-cumsum(vector) # build the cumulative sum of anomaly
   min<-which.min(vector)
   x<-1
   for (i in 1982:2011){
        df1<-subset(asc, asc$year==i |asc$year==i-1  | asc$year==i+1)
        DOY1<-seq(1, nrow(df1[df1$year == i-1,]), 1)
        DOY2<-seq(1, nrow(df1[df1$year == i,]), 1)
        DOY3<-seq(1, nrow(df1[df1$year == i+1,]), 1)
        DOY<-c(DOY1, DOY2, DOY3)
        df1$DOY<-DOY
        df1$DOY2<-seq(1, nrow(df1), 1)
        DOY2<-df1[df1$DOY == min & df1$year == i, ]
        DOY2<-DOY2$DOY2
        df2<-subset(df1, df1$DOY2>=DOY2-50 &  df1$DOY2<DOY2+50)
        df2$anomaly<-df2$precip-Q
        df2$accum<-cumsum(df2$anomaly)
        min_new<-df2[df2$accum == min(df2$accum), ]
        year<-min_new$year
        onset<-min_new$DOY
        results <-rbind(results, c(year, onset, name2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        x<-x+1
     }  
  }

write.table(results, file=paste("results_", name, ".csv", sep=""), row.names = FALSE, col.names = T, sep = ", ", quote=F)

end.time <- Sys.time()
time<-end.time-start.time
time
```

Comment: You may want to look at `data.table` and / or `dplyr` / `tidyverse` for your calculations, these may help you do this quicker.

Comment: Did you try profiling your code? I'm sure that would help finding out what takes the most time. At first glance, growing objects like `vector` should be avoided.